# Can multiple different vendor FPGAs exist on the same JTAG chain and be programmed?

Tags: fpga, jtag, configuration

During development work, JTAG is used to configure FPGAs. For the final version of the system there would be a few different options that will carry out automatic configuration of the FPGA actively or passively.

When using JTAG there are different programmers from different vendors that are to be used to program the device. I am curios how would one go about programming a board that has multiple FPGAs from different vendors e.g 1 Intel FPGA, 1 Xlinx, 1 Microsemi and 1 Lattice Semiconductor. Having different JTAG ports on the PCB may be too much inconvenient, if we combine them all through a single "JTAG chain" then, we can't program them all in one go since they need different type of programmers.

Since the JTAG itself is a standard interface and any FPGA that supports it can be communicated in a similar way, I assume that we should be able to use a single device to download the configuration bitstream of the different FPGAs in one go once they are chained together in a JTAG chain. Is this true?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, moreover widely used. But I would not recommend to mix different *FPGAs* though, it is inconvenient and inefficient in terms of required toolsets. But different memory devices/microcontrollers and such can definitely sit on the same JTAG chain.

Comment: Please don't do this. It would be like using metric and imperial screws to mount different corners of the board.

Comment: Voltage might also be an issue - differen chips could use different JTAG voltage levels. A Jtag chain must agree on a single JTAG voltage level to work properly.

Comment: Surely it depends on the programming tool and software?